# Canard limit cycle for certain singularly perturbed system (Is there a contradictory situation?)

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, asymptotics, limit-cycles

From the figures of page  478  and  479 of   [this   paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0062381) one find  that the  author probably  means that we have  a  (canard) limit cycle for the system

$$\begin{cases} x'=y-x^2\\ y'=\epsilon(a-x) \end{cases}$$

On the other hand it can be easily shown that the system under consideration
has no  limit cycle  when $a\neq 0$. Here is  a proof:

## Proof:

Putting $x:=x+a,\;y:=y-a^2$ we would obtain the following system:

$$\begin{cases} x'=y-x^2-2ax\\ y'=-\epsilon x\end{cases}$$

When  $a\neq 0$ the  system has no closed orbit by the  following  lemma  which is  a  restatement of  a  lemma in the  paper: A. Lins Neto, W. de Melo and C.C. Pugh, On Liénard Equations, Proc. Symp. Geom. and Topol., Lectures Notes in Math. 597, Springer–Verlag, 1977 pp. 335–357.

## Lemma:

Assume that $f$ is  an even polynomial  and  $g$ is  an odd polynomial  with $xg(x) \neq 0$ for  all  $x\neq 0$ then the  Liénard equation $$(1)\;\;\begin{cases} x'=y-(f(x)+g(x))\\ y'=-x\end{cases}$$ does not have  any  closed orbit.

The idea of the  proof  of  lemma, which I learned from the  above reference, is  based on the  following:

The  system $(1)$ is  transversal to $$(2)\;\;\begin{cases} x'=y-f(x)\\ y'=-x\end{cases}$$ but $(2)$ has a  center at origin. This  obviously implies that $(1)$ can not  have  a  closed orbit.

According to this situation we ask:

> Does the  figure  in pages 478  and  479 really claim that the above  system has a limit cycle? So is not a contradictory situation here?

I am interested in this  question since 1999 when I was trying to learn the  concept "Canard Limit Cycle". In my PhD thesis, I presented this question,  among other questions  about [two other interpretations of  "Canard"](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Canards#Methods). My questions were  result of my doubt or misunderstanding about the three methods of interpretations of "Canard": Nonstandard analysis asymptotic analysis and blow up.

**I wrote in my thesis:** *"However the author of this thesis did not understand these three interpretations of Canard concept completely but he feels that in each interpretation there is a kind of quasi contradictory situation". Then I wrote in my thesis the reasons for such guess about such possible contradictory situations.*

Comment: @YCor  Thank you for adding "ODE" tag. But was not the tag "Limit cycle"  an  appropriate tag?

Comment: Because it's somewhat narrow: it's a tag with 0 follower at the moment, so I tend to erase such tags (a tag with too few followers makes little sense). Listing questions tagged "limitcycle" now yields 26 questions (mostly by you). A search on "limit cycle" yields 36 answers, mostly the same. Anyway I don't mind if you put this tag again.

Comment: @YCor  I am sorry for this  second message. Now  I realize the  meaning of  ["The  number of  follower"](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3614/the-meaning-of-the-number-of-followers-of-a-tag). I think that the  number of  followers of  a  given tag is  usually very  less than the real number of participant who are interested in that subject. But you are right that in "Limit cycle" tag almost all questions are mine. Any way thank you for  your attention to this question and adding ODE tag which was really a  relevant tag.

Comment: Doesn't the lemma you cite only apply if a<0?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy  The  positive  or  negative case  can be easily transformed to each other by  change of  coordinate $x:=-x$.

Comment: @YCor  I personally believe that a "tag" (or generally speaking "an idea") with too few followers is  not  necessarily a tag (or an idea) which makes little  sense. Are you agree?

Comment: I agree. As a tag, "limitcycles" seems a reasonably focussed tag, and I should probably have kept it. At least you should follow it;)

Comment: Not substantial, but isn't the new system 
$$\begin{cases} x'=(y-a^2)-(x+a)^2=y-x^2{\color{red} -}2ax\\ y'=\epsilon (a-x-a)=-\epsilon x\end{cases}$$

Comment: @PietroMajer  Yes you are completely right. Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 2):

The figures 3.2 and 3.3 in Eckhaus's 1983 paper refer to the degenerate case that the function $f(x)$ in the differential equations
$$\begin{cases} x'=y-f(x)\\ 
y'=\epsilon(a-x) \end{cases}
$$
is quadratic at the origin, but the later analysis and demonstration of limit cycles assumes that $f(x)$ is cubic at the origin (as it is in the Van der Pol equation 3.3.2 in Eckhaus's paper). This is indeed required, see 
a later [paper by Braaksma](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01053807) (page 487).
Note that equation 3.5.5 of Eckhaus gives the radius squared of the periodic solution as proportional to $1/g'(0)$, where $f'(x)=xg(x)$. This diverges for a quadratic $f(x)$, when $g'(0)=0$, consistent with the expectation that a cubic $f(x)$ is needed for a limit cycle.

So if one restricts oneself to the explicit calculations (assuming a cubic $f$) rather than the initial figures (for a quadratic $f$) there is not really "a contradictory situation" in Eckhaus's 1983 paper.

Comment: Thanks  again for  your  answer. did  you already experienced working on canard limit cycles  based on either interpretations mentioned in the question, Non standard, blow up and asymptotic analysis? Any way your current answwer is very help full to me I will read the paper of  Eckhaus again and your answer help me to follow his paper easier. My main problem with the  non  standard approach by  Zvonkin and  shubin was the following For $\epsilon=0$ all horizontal line are solution curves(without any RETURN. But for  small $\epsilon$ they frequently assume that we  have  a Poincare return map

Comment: so what is the  domain of the poincare map they are working in?why is it legal to assume  a  global  domain for  for  Poincare  map. I remember when  i was a PHD student I realy tried to understand these approaches(3 approaches) but such kind of questions were my main obstructions for  continuation. I am  still curious about "CANARD". So i am curious  if you already experience researching on these subject.

Comment: Yes it is  understandable. i will try to understand it. The first thing i need is that i have to forget my mentality and  feeling of "quasi-contradictions" which i  was suffering during my phd study about this subject. If i orget that  i can follow the subject more clear and more relax. believe me that I really appreciate your great help by your answer. The reason i consider another bounty is that perhaps I would receive some other points which probably help me to convince myself.After all the canard is  a beautiful and mysterious concept. The mysterious point is that it is  observed by Non

Comment: by Non standard analysis. It is  interesting to imagine how they realized such concept just with non standard approach(As you know Reeb recommended his  students to keep track limit cycles by non standard approaches.  BTW, did you read my previeous comment on Zvonkin and  shubin paper(the legality of  assuming of  a  global domain for  Poincare returen map)?

Comment: I hope that realize the reason of  concerns about the  canard concept

Comment: a suggestion: I think the bounty will attract more response if you can formulate a somewhat more precise question, so that readers have a feeling what they should focus on; that is not quite clear at present.

Comment: Yes thank you  for this  suggestion. It requires I read both paper of  Eckhaus (again) and  the paper you kindly shared me in your answer. BTW did you read my comment on Zvonkin and  Shubin paper too?In my PHD studies  I was really unconvinced how they assume and legalize the poincare return map(somewhat globally) for  smal $\epsilon$)

Comment: that particular item (justification of Poincaré return map) could be a good focused question, to which I have no answer at present (but quite possibly other MO users might have)

Comment: Just a general question about Poincare return map? When it is legal to be define: I  know two answers  for this  question: first when we have a periodic orbit and  we draw a  cross section on it. Then as  a  consequence of  flow  box theorem and continuity of  flow we are able to deine  LEGALY the Poincare return map. The second case is the  existence  of a  weak focus a  non degenerate singularity with purely imaginary eiginvalues. These two case can be  adapted for  a  family of vector fields $V_{\epsilon}$ when $V_0$ has a periodic orbit or a weak focus singularity.

Comment: But in singular perturbation, for $\epsilon=0$ all orbits are straight lines THERE IS NO ANY RETURN.  after  all I think that the  concept of canard is very  beautiful and  mysterious which need to be  more  digested, understood and paid attention. In particular the canards of  Non standards and  asymptotic analysis. May  i  am  missing some  thing? I look forward to hear your comments and  i appreciate your  attention to this  subject.  BTW, to what extents  the appearence $\epsilon$-galaxi and "transfer principal" in this paper play a  crucial rule?Did you read the paper in details?

Answer (score 0):

The updated question asks for the validity of an analysis of the limit cycle based on the Poincaré return map, for which the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ is singular. This has been studied in [Asymptotic analysis of the peeling-off point of a French duck](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Asymptotic-analysis-of-the-peeling-off-point-of-a-Macgillivray-Liu/8fe96ca04414613ffce3913318bf854e7b13d3ad) (1994), for the specific case of the Van der Pol oscillator
$$
\begin{cases} \epsilon x'=y-f(x),\;\;f(x)=\tfrac{1}{3}x^3+\tfrac{1}{2}x^2,\\ 
y'=-(x+\alpha). \end{cases} 
$$

The Poincaré map gives a power series in $\epsilon$ for the values of $\alpha$ where a "canard" = "duck" limit cycle exists. The singularity at $\epsilon=0$ gives an additional contribution $\propto e^{-k/\epsilon}$, for a full expression of the form
$$\alpha=\alpha_{\rm Poincaré}+C\epsilon^{-1/2}\exp[-k/\epsilon],$$
$$\alpha_{\rm Poincaré}=\epsilon+12\epsilon^2+346\epsilon^3+15186\epsilon^4+o(\epsilon^4)$$
(explicit expressions for the coefficients $C$ and $k$ are given as well).